# Roaming profiles using vault credentials (instead of user credentials)

Tags: windows-8, network-shares, roaming-profiles, credentials-manager

I have a share on the server where roaming profiles are stored. Some clients use their vault accounts (through Credential manager) to access the server resources because their local accounts do not exist on the server. (This is mainly for users with Windows 8 live accounts.)

When I set their roaming profile path to point to the server share, their vault account aparently isn't used. So I am getting event ID 1521: Access denied to roaming profile.

Is there any way to force the use of vault account on roaming profiles? Or is my approach wrong and should these Windows 8 users not use roaming profiles?